# how to pull a stored field from an elastic search index, in R?

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am trying to pull stored field from an elastic search index in R. The field is called "text" and in Kibana I can see it is present for the index "document-000002". When specifying "text" as a value for parameter stored_fields I don't get it pulled, instead only "_index", "_type", "_id", "_score" and "_source" are present in the resulting list (first two lines of code). When I tested the line with source parameter, element "_source" was an empty list. What do I need to do to have "text" present in search output?

**An exemplary record from ES, accessed via Kibana:**

```
{
  "_index": "document-000002",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "AS_63689606",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "visitid": "65_63209606",
    "processingdate": "2022-08-24 17:24-0400",
    "gender": "male",
    "facility": "40998",
    "user": "JOHNDOE",
    "customer": "656"
  },
  "fields": {
    "processingdate": [
      "2022-08-24T21:24:00.000Z"
    ],
    "servicedate": [
      "2022-08-22T22:05:00.000Z"
    ],
    "text": [
      "an exemplary text I want to pull"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Tried code:**

```
library(elastic)
docs <- Search(c, "document-000002", size = 8, stored_fields = "text")$hits$hits
docs <- Search(c, "document-000002", size = 8, stored_fields = c("text", "servicedate"))$hits$hits
docs <- Search(c, "document-000002", size = 8, source = "text")$hits$hits
```

**info on “fields” parameter for ?Search:**

(character) The selective stored fields of the document to return for each hit. Not specifying any value will cause no fields to return. Note that in Elasticsearch v5 and greater, fields parameter has changed to stored_fields, which is not on by default. You can however, pass fields to source parameter

ES version in use: 7.3.1
Elastic package version in use: 1.2.0

Comment: do you need to take the elastic package? thats json data that can be easily parsed with other packages. if you are not restricted, use eg jsonlite?

Comment: https://github.com/ropensci/elastic#parsing

Comment: I need elastic to establish a connection to ES, as the jsons of interest reside in ES. For your 2nd comment, I tried to use parameter raw = T, but it still does not return any of the stored fields.

Comment: I can provide you a solution how to extract the info from the raw json as you posted above. I can't give a full solution for elasic, bcs I don't have access.

Comment: Please, share your partial solution, it might be useful too. Sadly, the jsons I need are indexed in elastic search and I don't know of any other library for R than elastic, that provides interface to access to ES.

Comment: @sckott I have read many of your valuable contributions, at the R and elastic search interface. Do you have any thoughts to share on the described issue?